# Make custom fields appear on category array, on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I wonder how can I have some categories custome fields apearing on this category array, with the present code, only the category term is being printed.

```
<?php
        $terms = get_terms('productcat');
        foreach ($terms as $key => $term) {
        $link = get_term_link($term);
        $cat_ttl =the_field('cat_ttl');
        $cat_img =the_field('featured_image');
        echo '<li>
                <a href="'.$link.'">
                  <div class="imager"><img src="'.$cat_ttl.'" alt="商品"></div>
                  <div class="right">
                     <h3>'.$cat_ttl.'</h3>
                     <p class="det">'.$term->slug.'</p>
                  </div>

                </a>
             </li>';
        }
      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the right grammar for it:

```
<?php
          $terms = get_terms('productcat');
          foreach ($terms as $key => $term) {
            $link = get_term_link($term);
            $image = get_field('featured_image', $term);
            $cat_ttl =get_field('cat_ttl', $term);
            echo '<li>
              <a href="'.$link.'">
                <div class="imager"><img src="'.$image.'" alt="商品"></div>
                <div class="right">
                  <h3>'.$cat_ttl.'</h3>
                  <p class="det">'.$term->slug.'</p>
                </div>

              </a>
            </li>';
          }
            ?>
```